# Switching orientations causes UIButton redraw

Tags: iphone, uibutton, three20

[image: http://i56.tinypic.com/33f6mmf.png]

I'm switching to landscape and it redraws the UIButton.  here is the button code.

```
plusButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bounds.size.width - 60.0f,       28.0f, 45.0f,90.0f)] autorelease ];
[plusButton setImage:TTIMAGE(@"bundle://morebutton.png")
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[plusButton showsTouchWhenHighlighted];
[plusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButtonDidPress:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:plusButton];
```

This is a TTMessageitemcell (THREE20)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this being called in drawRect or something similar? It looks as if it's creating a new instance of the button each time a drawing method is called. Try making plus button an instance variable of your cell and initialise it in the init method. Then you can set frame and other properties in the drawing method while only using one instance of the button. You can then release the button in dealloc.

tl;dr: looks as if you're adding multiple instances of the button in a drawing method eg. drawRect: or layoutSubviews.

Tim

Comment: it's in the subclassed TTMessageItemcell,  it's being called under (void)layoutSubviews, the tableview starts in portrait and this is what happens when orientation is changed to landscape.

Comment: Yes. Every time the cell redraws you're adding another button. You need to initialise this button outside of the drawing method as stated above. Such as in - (void) init.

Comment: You'll want to use the init method that the TTMessageItemcell uses and call [super …]; then init this object. You'll want to define it as an instance variable too in your header so it has a global scope within your class.

Comment: I gave up TTTableMessageView is subclassed of TTTableLinkItemcell, i've just placed the button on the right for now. My flow is VC-Datasource-Model-ItemCell. I'll dig through Three20 later today, might be something simple like removefromsuper on reuse.

Comment: I've not worked with Three20 myself. But can safely say after replicating your code in a UITableViewCell subclass that its to do with the fact when you rotate the device layout subviews is called and your code creates a new button (as you're using alloc/init and adding subview) rather than updating its frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
plusButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bounds.size.width - 60.0f,       28.0f, 45.0f,90.0f)] autorelease ];

[plusButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];


[plusButton setImage:TTIMAGE(@"bundle://morebutton.png")
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[plusButton showsTouchWhenHighlighted];
[plusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButtonDidPress:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:plusButton];
```

Comment: Autoresizing the button still leaves the older button from the portrait landscape, if i hardcode bounds.size.width - 60.0f to 260, i only get the one button, as it doesn't move it.